# How to attach external library in twig file with parameters?

Tags: 8, theming

I have below code to share on LINE messenger

```
<div class="line-it-button" data-lang="en" data-type="share-b" data-url="{{ current_path }}" style="display: none;"></div>
<script src="https://d.line-scdn.net/r/web/social-plugin/js/thirdparty/loader.min.js" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```

How to include JS using attach_library?

```
{{ attach_library('https://d.line-scdn.net/r/web/social-plugin/js/thirdparty/loader.min.js') }}
```

How to attach **async="async"** **defer="defer"** ?

Tried using

```
{{ attach_library('https://d.line-scdn.net/r/web/social-plugin/js/thirdparty/loader.min.js', { 'async' : 'async', 'defer' : 'defer'}) }}
```

But not working :(

Answer (score 2):

In your **theme.libraries.yml** file add below lines

```
theme.social:
  js:
    'https://d.line-scdn.net/r/web/social-plugin/js/thirdparty/loader.min.js' : { external: true, defer: true, async: true }
```

In your twig file

```
{{ attach_library('theme.social') }}
```

Clear cache & it works :)